# Cannot install php-mcrypt even using EPEL/REMI repositories

Tags: php, mcrypt, epel

I'm working on a VPS of Godaddy (Economy plan with WHM & CPanel) developing an appliacation based on Laravel 4, so to install correctly it's necessary to have php-mcrypt extension but can't install even installing EPEL and REMI repositories and it's too rare because I'm a digitalocean VPS and after having installed EPEL and REMI I could install the php-mcrypt without any problems.

I'm trying to download the php-mcrypt using:

- yum install php-mcrypt
- yum install php5-mcrypt
- yum install php54-mcrypt
- yum install php-mcrypt*

Even trying to install PHP (I have already installed) but the console display always:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.easynews.com
 * epel: mirrors.solfo.com
 * extras: mirror.hmc.edu
 * remi: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: centos.sonn.com
base                                                        | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                      | 3.4 kB     00:00
remi                                                        | 2.9 kB     00:00
updates                                                     | 3.4 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
No package php-mcrypt available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I don't know what happened, I hope can you help me.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

On WHM Control Panel, go to **Apache update**  and find the section called **Exhaustive Options List** and finally find **Mcrypt** extension to install and that's all!